# aligning navbar images alignment

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center my Navbar at the top of my page, but it's currently positioned on the top right. I've attempted various approaches, but I can't seem to get it to center properly. I'd like the Navbar to be both horizontally and vertically centered.On my main page, I have a section with my name and some text, but they aren't aligning as I intend. The text isn't centered correctly, and I'd like both my name and the text to be perfectly centered both horizontally and vertically.Additionally, I'm facing an issue where my Navbar is not showing up anymore. I've reviewed my code, but I can't figure out why it's not appearing. Furthermore, I have three images with accompanying descriptions that I'm trying to align in a row. Despite trying various properties, I'm struggling to get them to align properly.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Personal Project</title>

  <!--  bootstrap and aos  -->
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/aos.css">

  <!--  css   -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section id="mainPage">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="main-display">
            <h1 id="name-title">Mazin Esmail</h1>
            <h2>Software Developer</h2>
            <h2>Student</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="about-me">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="heading-about">
          <h1 id="about--me" class="display-5">About me</h1>


          <p id="border-line-about"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="about-page-text">
      <p>Hello!, I am a student at Cal State San Bernardino and I am studying the field of computer science. I love going out to view new things and play the sports that I love. As an aspiring software engineer I want to solve real life problems and create
        web applications to further thrive a positive impact to the world. </p>


    </div>

    <div class="about-me-pics">
      <figure id="las-vegas-pic">
        <img src="assets/img/IMG_0525.jpeg" height="400" width="400" />
        <figcaption>Las Vegas, Nevada</figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure id="basketball-pic">
        <img src="assets/img/IMG_0816.jpeg" height="400" width="400" />
        <figcaption>Fontana, California</figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure id="mountain-pic">
        <img src="assets/img/IMG_2825.jpeg" height="400" width="400" />
        <figcaption>Fontana, California</figcaption>
      </figure>

    </div>
  </section>
```

```
  <!--  bootstrap and aos js  -->
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8c2adfc9c1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
  <script>
    AOS.init();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
@font-face {
    font-family: Oswald;
    src: url("../fonts/Oswald-Medium.ttf");
  }
  
  html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
  
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Oswald, serif;
    
  }
  
  
 
  .navbar {
    position: sticky;
    top: -50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 3px;
     height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
}
  
  
  .nav-link-home {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/images1/Shadows-Backgrounds-HD.jpg);
    position: absolute;

  }
  
  .nav-link {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .navbar * {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 100%;
    
  }
  
  .nav-item {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .nav-link-home {
    color: white;
  }
  
  #mainPage {
    background-image: url(https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/images1/Shadows-Backgrounds-HD.jpg);
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    color: aliceblue;
   
  }
  
  .main-display {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 290%; 
    transform: translateY(-50%);

  }
  
  @keyframes fadeInOut {
    0%,
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  #about-me {
    background-color: lightblue;
    min-height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #border-line-about {
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    left: 22%;
    margin-top: 90vh;
  }
  
  #content-text {
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -888%;
    left: -42%;
    position: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70vh;

  }
  
  .about-me-pics {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: -190rem; 
    flex-direction: row;
    
  }
  
  #las-vegas-pic {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 330px;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  }
  
  .about-me-pics figure {
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
    width: 30%; 
    height: 100vh;
    
  }
  
  #basketball-pic {
    transform: translate(20%, 0%);
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #mountain-pic {
    transform: translate(-5%, -103%);
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .about-page-text {
    margin-top: -39rem; 
    font-family: 'Font Name', sans-serif;
  }
```

Comment: minimise the code this isn't very clear.